# How to generate multible plots from one dataframe in a row in r?

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I am quite new to R and am trying to simplify my codes as I often create different plots from one dataframe. I have experimented with loops but have not achieved anything yet.
Librarys needed:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
```

I have a data set with different measurements over a period of time in several batches similar to this one:

```
x<-rbind(as.data.frame(cbind(batch = "A", datetime = format(seq(as.POSIXct("2023-01-01 06:00:00", tz="UTC"), by="min", length.out=50), "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%OS"),
                            rbind(
                                  as.data.frame(cbind(measurement = "ref_Flow",values = rnorm(50, mean = 1.6, sd = 0.005e+01))),
                                  as.data.frame(cbind( measurement = "Flow" ,values = rnorm(50, mean = 1.6, sd = 0.008))),
                                  as.data.frame(cbind(measurement = "ref_Temp",values = rnorm(50, mean = 23, sd = 0.5e+01))),
                                  as.data.frame(cbind(measurement = "Temp",values = rnorm(50, mean = 23, sd = 1))),
                                  as.data.frame(cbind(measurement = "ref_Hum",values = rnorm(50, mean = 50, sd = 1e+01))),
                                  as.data.frame(cbind(measurement = "Hum", values = rnorm(50, mean = 50, sd = 5)))
                                   ))),
         as.data.frame(cbind(batch = "B", datetime = format(seq(as.POSIXct("2023-01-05 08:43:00", tz="UTC"), by="min", length.out=50), "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%OS"),
                             rbind(
                               as.data.frame(cbind(measurement = "ref_Flow",values = rnorm(50, mean = 0.16, sd = 0.005e+01))),
                               as.data.frame(cbind( measurement = "Flow" ,values = rnorm(50, mean = 0.16, sd = 0.01))),
                               as.data.frame(cbind(measurement = "ref_Temp",values = rnorm(50, mean = 23, sd = 0.5e+01))),
                               as.data.frame(cbind(measurement = "Temp",values = rnorm(50, mean = 23, sd = 0.8))),
                               as.data.frame(cbind(measurement = "ref_Hum",values = rnorm(50, mean = 50, sd = 1e+01))),
                               as.data.frame(cbind(measurement = "Hum", values = rnorm(50, mean = 50, sd = 2)))
                             ))),
         as.data.frame(cbind(batch = "C", datetime = format(seq(as.POSIXct("2023-01-20 07:33:00", tz="UTC"), by="min", length.out=50), "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%OS"),
                             rbind(
                               as.data.frame(cbind(measurement = "ref_Flow",values = rnorm(50, mean = 0.16, sd = 0.005e+01))),
                               as.data.frame(cbind( measurement = "Flow" ,values = rnorm(50, mean = 0.16, sd = 0.002))),
                               as.data.frame(cbind(measurement = "ref_Temp",values = rnorm(50, mean = 23, sd = 0.5e+01))),
                               as.data.frame(cbind(measurement = "Temp",values = rnorm(50, mean = 23, sd = 1.3))),
                               as.data.frame(cbind(measurement = "ref_Hum",values = rnorm(50, mean = 50, sd = 1e+01))),
                               as.data.frame(cbind(measurement = "Hum", values = rnorm(50, mean = 50, sd = 10)))
                             ))))
x$values<-as.numeric(x$values)
x$datetime<-as.POSIXct(x$datetime)
```

I would like to plot measurements and ref_measurements per batch. I would do this for each batch and measurement:

```
ggplot(subset(x, batch == "A") %>% 
         filter(measurement %in% c("Flow", "ref_Flow")))+
  aes(x = datetime, y = values, color = measurement)+
  geom_line()+
  labs(title = "Batch: A",
       subtitle = "Measurement: Flow")
```

How can I integrate a loop (or similar) to not repeat the code x times?

Comment: Does it need to be a loop? One option is to use `+ facet_wrap(~batch, scales = "free")`, you'd just need to get creative with the y-axis specifications.

Comment: this is basically a good idea and works, but my real dataset is much bigger, so that I then have mini plots on which I would only recognize something by strongly zooming in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a for loop, storing the plots in a list

```
pl <- list()
for(i in unique(x$batch)){
pl[[i]] <- ggplot(subset(x, batch == i) %>% 
               filter(measurement %in% c("Flow", "ref_Flow"))) +
             aes(x = datetime, y = values, color = measurement) +
             geom_line() +
             labs(title = paste("Batch:", i), subtitle = "Measurement: Flow")}
```

Plot or save later by *batch*

```
pl$A

<<plot>>
```

```
pdf("file.pdf")

pl$A

dev.off()
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you!

Not relevant here but can I actually integrate a second loop to bypass the filtering of the measurements? I tried that but it doesn't work (respectively how do I control the plot to look at it?)      `
    pl <- list()
for(i in unique(x$batch)){
  for(j in unique(x$measurement)){
  pl[[i[j]]] <- ggplot(subset(x, batch == i & measurement == j)) +
    aes(x = datetime, y = values, color = measurement) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(title = paste("Batch:", i), subtitle = "Measurement:", j)
  }}

Comment: @Sontje Not sure what you mean. You can look at it by typing e.g. `pl$X` for all batches. Or save the plots and open them in a pdf viewer. If you want to bypass the filtering you can leave out the line `filter(measurement %in% c("Flow", "ref_Flow"))` in your code. Or do you want to group by batches and additionally all measurements creating 18 plots?

Comment: @Sontje Try `pl <- list(); for(i in unique(x$batch)){ for(j in unique(x$measurement)){ pl[[unique(paste(i, j))]] <- ggplot(subset(x, batch == i & measurement == j)) + aes(x = datetime, y = values, color = measurement) + geom_line() + labs(title = paste("Batch:", i), subtitle = "Measurement:", j) }}`